# Can I crawl SharePoint Online content using an on-premise search service application?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, search, sharepoint-on-prem, hybrid-solution

We were initially planning on doing a completely hybrid search setup, but it came to our attention that an on-premise index is necessary for a piece of software we utilize.

So now, we have a Cloud SSA which indexes our content for searching in our SPO "intranet", and we have an on-premise index that's utilized internally for internal site collections.

I know you can create a result source for a remote SharePoint, however, since our on-prem has already been crawled and had the content sent to the SPO index, when I use a promoted result block it still shows content from on-premise because it's IN the SPO index ...

I basically don't even want to do that, can I just create a content source for our SPO site collection and crawl it? Is this supported and what's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, we can Index On-Premises content and store in O365 Index and it looks like vice versa is not possible.

Even in many Technet article it has been mentioned like this topology.

- The crawl component gets content from your on-premises farm and sends
  this content to the search index in Office 365. It uses connectors to
  interact with the content sources, and uses the crawl database to
  store both temporary and historical information about the items it
  crawls, just like a regular crawl component.
- The search administration component runs system processes that are
  essential to search, just as for a standard SSA.
- We recommend running all searches from Office 365, as cloud hybrid
  search is optimized for this. But, you can set up site search in
  SharePoint Server to get search results from your search index in
  Office 365. If you set up search in an on-premises site collection to
  query your Office 365 index, this query processing component passes
  queries from the search box to the Office 365 index, and results from
  the Office 365 index to the search box.

[image]

Reference: [Plan your Topology](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Plan-cloud-hybrid-search-for-SharePoint-33926857-302c-424f-ba78-03286cf5ac30#)

[Hybrid Search in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hybrid-search-in-SharePoint-1a7269ba-5aa7-481b-b608-030c58fa932e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 1):

You should first clear up your CloudIndex. Unfortunately it is a very bad idea to click on "Index Reset" in your OnPremise Cloud-SSA. There's some [PowerShell for that job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2016/05/18/cloud-search-service-application-removing-items-from-the-office-365-search-index/).

Maybe this architecture matches your needs ([Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Plan-cloud-hybrid-search-for-SharePoint-33926857-302c-424f-ba78-03286cf5ac30#bkmk_sensitive_content)):

Set up cloud hybrid search in combination with hybrid federated search.
Illustration showing a combined set-up of cloud hybrid search, hybrid federated search, and enterprise search.

[image]

- Plan content sources for the cloud Search service application (cloud SSA) in SharePoint Server that cover all on-premises content except the sensitive content. The metadata for the crawled content is added the search index in Office 365.
- Plan enterprise search in SharePoint Server to crawl the sensitive, on-premises content, see [Plan search in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263400.aspx). Plan content sources for the SSA that cover the sensitive content. The metadata from the crawled, sensitive content is added to the search index in SharePoint Server.
- If your users need results from the Office 365 search index in on-premises SharePoint sites, plan hybrid federated search from SharePoint Server to display search results from the search index in SharePoint Server and from the search index in Office 365, see [Plan hybrid federated search for SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771045.aspx).